# Is the Ashkenazi pronunciation of the kamatz "aw" or "uh"?

Tags: grammar-dikduk, ashkenazi, vowels-nekudot

I have seen sources, for example the Artscroll transliterated siddur, that say that the Ashkenazi pronunciation of the kamatz vowel is "aw," as in the first syllable of "often," whereas other sources, for example the Artscroll Schottenstein Talmud, say that the pronunciation is "uh" as in the first syllable of "ago."  Which is correct?

Comment: People pronounce English differently. Using IPA would be better for this kind of question.

Comment: It's pronounced [ɔ] in most Ashkenazi traditions.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: Answer varies among type of Ashkenazim. Chassidim pronounce differently than Litvaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Europe it was always pronounced as "uh". Listen to this clip of [Rav Moshe Feinstein](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KI1RvrD9c1Q). Today, in America, "aw" is the more Americanized pronunciation, and "uh" is the more *Yeshivish* pronunciation.

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya and thanks for this first answer. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: To my ear, most Israelis and Europeans who use ashkenazi pronunciation today will pronounce a kamatz the way the Brits pronounce the vowel in ‘hot’. I’m not an IPA expert but I believe that’s /ɒ/. I have no idea if that’s what you mean by an ‘uh’ sound.

Comment: @JoelK It's [ɔ] you're looking for I believe.

Comment: OP, Rav Moshe was Russian and in my experience many Russian Jews pronounce komatz this way (such as Lubavitch). But most Ashkenazim use "o" as in "hot" as mentioned in the comment by @JoelK

Comment: @ezra I haven’t got the most trained ear. I confess that I find the distinction between the open-mid back vowel (ɔ) and the open back vowel (ɒ) to be very subtle

Comment: I highly doubt in Europe it was always pronounced any one way. Surely there were variations in different parts of Europe let alone different time periods.

Comment: There are many slight variations of how to pronounce the "uh" sound, such as the way Brits pronounce the vowel in "hot", the way Americans pronounce the vowel in "ago", the way the Brits pronounce the vowel in "ago".
To say what I am saying in IPA, the kamatz sound would be ɞ, ɔ, or ɒ, or one of the many slight variations of those.
What I understood from the OPs question was about the "aw" (ɑ) as in "often". That pronunciation is unique to Americans.
(I used https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPA_vowel_chart_with_audio to get the sounds mentioned in this comment)